# GridLayout doesn't work

Tags: java, swing, oop, layout-manager, grid-layout

here's my code:

```
PresidentVote(){
        setName("PresCandidate");
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Candidates for President"));

        for(int row=0; row<PresidentTable.tblNatPresident.getRowCount(); row++){
            setLayout(new GridLayout(row, 2));
            String name=PresidentTable.tblNatPresident.getValueAt(row, 0).toString();

            JLabel lblName=new JLabel(name);
            JRadioButton radioVote=new JRadioButton();
            lblName.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));

            add(lblName); add(radioVote);
        }
    }
```

but the one that will appear looks like this:

[image]

and i'm trying to achieve like this:

> name | radiobutton
>
> name | radiobutton

and the number of rows will depend on how many rows the jtables was. and only two columns.

i don't really know i mean did i violate something in the codes? or is there something that i should put for it to properly work? please help thank you so much :)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Please improve this question. And why are you re-adding the layout within the for loop? How many rows and columns are you expecting? And why use JLabels rather than simply giving the JRadioButtons  text?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels i already edited it thank you :) and oh that didn't occur to my mind i'll try that now heheh thank you!! :)

Comment: Set the layout **once**, give it 2 columns and variable rows: `GridLayout(0, 2)` -- the 0 is important as it means a variable number of rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters you need to move your setLayout before the loop as it is just overriding it each iteration for no reason, therefore you need to change the y value to the amount of rows. Secondly change swap the values within the grid layout so it looks something like this...

```
setLayout(new GridLayout(2, PresidentTable.tblNatPresident.getRowCount()));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the radio button and a label to be put together in a single cell, wrap them in a panel and put the panel into the cell.  Remember that the panel needs it's own layout (although the default flow layout may work for you)

As an alternative, I think setting the text (label?) of the radio button might be cleaner (although slightly less flexible).